# webview, using loadData at onResume loses history

Tags: android, html, webview, browser-history

I have this app which reads articles in a webview. When ArticleActivity is first started, the html of the webpage is actually downloaded into a string and parsed to make it look like a mobile site, then I use `wb.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);`. The downloading occurs in an asynctask since I can't do internet activity on the ui thread, but for now, whenever a link on the page is clicked, it just defaults to `loadUrl()` as per the webviewclient. I can use `goBack()` in history with this, no problem.

The problem lies with the search bar widget. I call SearchResultsActivity, which opens a webview and loads a url. When the user clicks on an article, SearchResultsActivity sends it BACK to ArticleActivity through an intent. The problem with that is that I want to use `loadData()` for the new article link, and I try to do that in `onResume()`, but nothing happens if I'm still on the previously loaded page. The log statement shows that the Url from `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` did make it, so I think the intent is good. I think this is due to a javascript "same origin" thing, so that's why if I use `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, the page loads. But if I try the back button now, the previously loaded page is blank! What do I do to preserve history when I load the new page?

```
class SearchWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // if it is morning sign out AND is an article, send url to ArticleActivity
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("morningsignout.com")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, url); // Put url in intent
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // Open w/ old articleActivity if exists
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

//        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
//        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}
```

from ArticleActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // URL from CategoryActivity
    String intentURL = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT);

    // Set webView to new article
    if (intentURL != null) new URLToMobileArticle(webView).execute(intentURL);
    else {
        // If statement is reached, then intent originated from SearchResultsActivity
        intentURL = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT);
        new URLToMobileArticle(webView).execute(intentURL);
        Log.d("ArticleActivity", "Loading: " + intentURL);
    }
}
```

what `URLToMobileArticle` is, `getArticles()` is the download/parsing function:

```
public URLToMobileArticle(WebView webview) {
    this.wb = webview;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return getArticle(params[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String html) {
    wb.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
    // wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(link, html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);
    Log.d("URLToMobileArticle", "Loaded webpage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that I can use shouldInterceptRequest() to always load the html in the way I see fit. I just need to ensure that I can distinguish between webpage urls and other requests like images or style sheets